# Getting installation directory for script executed as windows service

Tags: python, windows-services, cx-freeze, pywin32

I am using python to create a windows service using `pywin32` and `cx_freeze` to distribute it. I am freezing to an MSI to allow for installation of the program in any directory of the user's choice. The problem I am encountering is that when the service is installed by the service manager the process is executed with the working directory being `%WinDir%\System32` This causes a problem since the service grabs some configuration information from an ini file in the installation directory which there is not a defined absolute path to.

Is there a way to pass the installation directory to my application when the service is installed? Or is there a better way of ingesting the configuration file without the need for an absolute path definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to identify the installation directory from the Windows Registry. When a service is installed, the path to the executable is registered in the windows registry under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\
```